# Problems with if or statement in foreach

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Trying to make the update button turn red (danger bootstrap) if $hold1 or $hold2 = "Oversidder" but when running all buttons turn red. It echo's the rows from DB with the right values.

```
foreach ($stmt as $row)
{

$hold1 = $row['kampH1'];
$hold2 = $row['kampH2'];

echo '<tr>';
  echo '<td>'. $hold1 . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['kampH1M'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $row['kampH2M'] . '</td>';
  echo '<td>'. $hold2 . '</td>';
  echo '<td width=125>';

  if ($hold1 || $hold2 = "Oversidder") {

  echo '<a class="btn btn-danger" href="update.php? id='.$row['kampID'].'">Update</a>';}

   else
{
  echo '<a class="btn btn-success" href="update.php?id='.$row['kampID'].'">Update</a>';}
  echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: `=` is the assignment operator; `==` or `===` are comparison operators

Comment: `=` != `==`: You are assigning, not comparing! Change `=` to `==`

Comment: After your edit: `$hold1 || $hold2 = "Oversidder"` will also always be true (unless $hold == false). You want: `$hold1=="Oversidder  || $hold2 == "Oversidder"`

Comment: One of you should put your answer in an answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```
if ($hold1 || $hold2 = "Oversidder")
```

you have two mistakes:

**1.** `=` is the operator to assign a value to something, but you want to compare, which would be `==` ("lazy") or `===` ("exact" - including type).

So this

```
$hold2 = "Oversidder"
```

should be

```
$hold2 == "Oversidder"
// OR
$hold2 === "Oversidder"
```

**2.** If `$hold1` is something else than `NULL`, `false`, `0`, .. (any falsy value) this first condition will always be true, even if `$hold1=='foo'`

*Conclusion:*

What you want is:

```
//if   this is "Oversidder" OR this is "Oversidder"
if ( $hold1 == "Oversidder" || $hold2 == "Oversidder") {
     // do smth
}
```

In cases like this it's always a good idea to consult the manual:
[Comparison Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)
[Logical Operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)